# Set cookie in react native web view initial load and subsequent requests

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am trying to load an asp.net app in a react native web view that needs authentication. The user already logged in to the mobile app and I have the authentication cookie saved in the storage. I am looking for a way to pass this authentication cookie to my asp.net page in react native web view to automatically authenticate user without having to login again. I want the cookie to be sent for every subsequent requests to the asp.net app loaded in web view. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this one out?